# No route matches [Post] /characters/1/edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am trying to reach the edit page for my character class, but for some reason it is routing with a POST when it should be a GET. All similar questions have not helped.

Here is my edit function:

```
def edit
end
```

Here are my routes:

```
<%= button_to 'Edit Character', edit_character_path(@character) %>

characters_path GET /characters(.:format)   characters#index
POST    /characters(.:format)   characters#create
new_character_path  GET /characters/new(.:format)   characters#new
edit_character_path GET /characters/:id/edit(.:format)  characters#edit
character_path  GET /characters/:id(.:format)   characters#show
PATCH   /characters/:id(.:format)   characters#update
PUT /characters/:id(.:format)   characters#update
DELETE  /characters/:id(.:format)   characters#destroy
```

here is my edit link:

```
<%= button_to 'Edit Character', edit_character_path(@character) %>
```

Comment: edit link didn't go in, here it is: <%= button_to 'Edit Character', edit_character_path(@character) %>

Comment: For better assistance, please edit your question to include your Rails version and your routes.rb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `button_to`, acccording to [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to), generates a form, and the form method is `post`

Any reason for which you are ussing `button_to` ?

Otherwise you can just use a `link_to` and add a custom class:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit Character', edit_character_path(@character), class: 'my-custom-class' %>
```

so you can add the css for your custom class and make it look like a button

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I didn't know that about button_to

Comment: @OscarCourchaine Official [doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to):  ":method - Symbol of HTTP verb. Supported verbs are :post, :get, :delete, :patch, and :put. By default it will be :post."